# How do I specify a command line argument?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

How do I initialization the arguments of `main()`?

```
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
```

Always following error occurs:

```
// If the directory is not specified as a command-line argument,
// print usage.

if(argc != 2)
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("\nUsage: %s <directory name>\n"), argv[0]);
      return (-1);
   }
```

What can I do that this error does not occur?

I want to implement this example:

[Listing the Files in a Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200.aspx)

Comment: How do you call your program from the command line?

Comment: Give the program an argument on the command line

Comment: If you're running from the debugger, you can set that argument in your project properties.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you specify a command line argument at the command line prompt like:

```
> myprogram c:\TheDirectory
```

If you run your program from the debugger, you have to specify those command line arguments in your project property settings.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs8hbt1w(v=vs.90).aspx) for details (it's the same for c++):

> **To build and run the Command Line Parameters samples within Visual Studio**
>
> 1. In **Solution Explorer**, right-click the CmdLine1 project, and
>      then click **Set as StartUp Project**.
> 2. In **Solution Explorer**, right-click
>      the project, and then click **Properties**.
> 3. Open the **Configuration Properties** folder, and then click **Debug**.
> 4. In the **Command Line Arguments**
>      property, type the command-line parameters, and click **OK**. (See the
>      tutorial for an example.)
> 5. On the **Debug** menu, click **Start Without Debugging**.
> 6. Repeat the previous steps for CmdLine2.